# gapi.client.load stopped working for Google Tag Manager. How might it be fixed?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Sometime between this morning and yesterday evening, gapi.client.load('tagmanager', v2') started throwing an error. I have code that loads drive, analytics, auth using the same discovery call. These still work, while the GTM code has stopped working.

This call for tagmanager v2 formed by the call to gapi.client.load no longer works:
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tagmanager/v2/rest?fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&pp=0

If I remove the parameters, it works:
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tagmanager/v2/rest

This call for analytics v3 still works:
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/analytics/v3/rest?fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&pp=0

Here is the error returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "kind,name,version,rootUrl,servicePath,resources,parameters,methods,batchPath,id",
            "description": "Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'kind'."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: [ask] You didn't ask any question. Anyway it is error returned from Google service, I think you should ask them

Comment: I guess the question is "Will someone fix this issue?" I was pointed to Stack Overflow by Google: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support

Comment: Well, that is indeed a question.

Comment: Did you try to remove only the `kind` parameter?

Comment: The request is formed in the gapi.client.load call of the gapi client library. The same function is used for all the other modules. I don't see a way in the documentation to alter it: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md

Comment: So open an issue here https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues

Comment: Thanks. The issue is already raised there. I will hop on that thread. Though I don't believe it's an issue with the library, as it hasn't changed. It appears to be an issue with the discovery service. Something seems to have changed there.

Comment: Actually @JeffPierce the documentation pointed me to exactly what I needed to do to fix the issue - manually pass the discovery URL (with a `fields=` empty query param) as the first param of `gapi.client.load`